# How to install vs2022 from within an installation application?

Tags: .net, installation, frameworks, visual-studio-2022

I developed an installation application in VS2022 it installs fine on my machine, however when I try to run it on another PC it gives the error "You must install or update .NET to run this application.

How can I do this within the application?